# How to add project dependency (classes from another module/folder) in Grails?

Tags: grails

Is there a way for me to add dependencies from other folders/projects(non-grails, but definitely java projects) into my grails project? I've tried searching but didn't really get much of an answer.  :(

Comment: Did you try JARring the stuff you want and then adding the JAR to lib/ folder in your grails project?

Comment: It's not actually in jar, just a class.. I was able to add it as dependency for other modules with the help of gradle. I figured, I could do the same with grails?

Comment: Well, grails doesn't use gradle.  If it's just a class, why not copy it into `src/groovy`?

Comment: Well I was trying to avoid that path. lol.. Coz if update the model from the other module, I will have to update the copied ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use every possible library which is in a maven repository. So transform your java project to a maven or gradle project. Install your builded jar to maven repo and then you can add dependency in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy.

```
dependencies {
    compile "your.group:your.artifact:1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the code into your project somehow.

These are the options:

## JAR

Package your module as a `jar` file and copy this to your project's `lib/` directory.

## source code

Copy the source code for your module into `src/java/`

## Maven Artifact

Package your module as a maven artifact, and specify it in the `dependencies` closure of `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`.

Read more in the grails documentation at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configurationsAndDependencies